# Set button Height from a constant value defined in a class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, runtime, wpf-controls

I have an issue while trying to set the height of all my app buttons to a constant value. My project has many Windows and controls, and a requirement is all controls to have the same height in pixels, so I'd prefer to have that value storaged in a constant.

I have isolated the problem in a new project and getting the same error, the code is very simple. Let's say I have a class like this, with a namespace defined and a const string value:

```
namespace WpfApp.MyDesigner
{
    public class MyStyles
    {
        public const string NavigationBarHeight = "64";
    }
}
```

Then my app just open this .xaml view defined as a default Window with a Button on a Grid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.Views.WindowWithButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:WpfApp.MyDesigner"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WindowWithButton" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="{x:Static constants:MyStyles.NavigationBarHeight}" Height="64"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that I'm just trying to set the Width (or the Height, the error is the same) as the constant value defined on my before class, whose value is "64".

The namespace is added with:

```
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:WpfApp.MyDesigner"
```

And the const is correctly referenced in the Button definition with:

```
<Button Width="{x:Static constants:MyStyles.NavigationBarHeight}" Height="64"></Button>
```

But I get a runtime error specifying the value "64" is not valid for the Width property

[image]

I have tried to define the const as integer and deleting /bin and /obj folders before compiling, also trying with empty new projects, changing namespaces, class names... but error is always the same, I can't get that const value from my .xaml and I'm totally stuck with this part.

Comment: The constant must be of type double and not string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width property is defined in System.Windows.FrameworkElement as:

```
public double Width { get; set; }
```

so your constant should be

```
public const double NavigationBarHeight = 64;
```

instead of string.

Comment: Oh my god, that was the problem dude, thanks a lot. Now it's working, but even working I get always an error in console after I stop playing the app
File WindowWithButton.xaml -> Name "MyStyles" doesn't exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApp.MyDesigner".
It's weird that even working it throws related errors, I have deleted /bin and /obj and it's always the same

Answer (score 1):

if you are stuck with a `string` constant for some reason (e.g. it comes from 3rd party library), you can still use it by creating a Binding, which will take care of type convertion:

```
Height="{Binding Source={x:Static constants:MyStyles.NavigationBarHeight}}"
```

Comment: That solution works fine and now I can compile and run my project. But when I stop playing, Visual Studio always show this, it shows one error for each time I use that sentence (+100 times...) so it's annoying
Error XDG0008 
"MyStyles" doesn't exists in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApp.MyDesigner". WpfApp C:\Proyectos\trinitweb\WpfApp\Views\MainWindow.xaml